# Scrollbar doesn't show up in Chrome on OS X

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, kentico

So I have a site built using the Kentico CMS. On page load, sometimes the scroll bars will not show up in Chrome on Mac. They do show up in Safari, reliably. I previously had this issue with Safari, and added

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to my css, and that seemed to fix it. It's not working for Chrome, however.

I did notice that if I open up the dev console and then close it, it gains a scroll bar. If I change the CSS of an element to be width 99%, rather than 100%, it gains a scroll bar. However, this only works if I change the CSS that targets that element. If I change it just for that element (either with javascript or by modifying the element.style through the console), it does not gain a scroll bar.

There are no JavaScript errors upon opening the console.

My thought was to try to change the CSS itself with JavaScript, but I'm not positive how to do that.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Or how I could accomplish my plan?

I unfortunately can't reduce the problem any further. It seems to be the interaction of the whole site, including Kentico, so it doesn't seem possible to get a jsfiddle or anything.

Comment: Code sample would be very helpful

Comment: Markup is an entire website built through Kentico. I cannot reduce it to smaller than a whole page because it's a problem with the integration with Kentico itself. Code sample would as well be the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. This was caused by the following css:

```
html {
    overflow-y: inherit;
}
```

I do not know why this caused the problem. I commented out this line, and the issue was resolved.